# Import to python package

Tags: python-2.7, import, package

I need to import Decimal to all my .py files in a given python package in my Django project.

Is there a way of doing this universally, rather declaring the below in each file?

```
from decimal import *
```

I was thinking adding this line into the `__init__.py` for the package, but this doesn't seem to work

I am using Python 2.7.5